# sort_values function returning different output for same file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a xlsx file and same in csv format, i read them using `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.read_csv` respectively and then store data after reading those files in a dataframe. If i print the stored values, i see no difference, but then when i sort and compare, i am seeing difference between the two values, can someone help?

```
df = fields_df.sort_values(['register',1], ascending=[False, False])

df1 = fields_df1.sort_values(['register',1], ascending=[False, False])
```

`fields_df` and `fields_df1` are the two dataframes after reading from xlsx and csv resp.
Before sorting `fields_df` and `fields_df1` when compared, are exactly same. But after sorting i see difference in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can investigate difference of dataframes by:

```
out = fields_df.compare(fields_df1)
print (out)
```

Then test rows in `out` DataFrame, e.g.if different types, or some trailing spaces for strings columns or maybe some datetime columns only in excel DataFrame.

```
print (fields_df.dtypes)
print (fields_df1.dtypes)
```

Comment: THere was a diff in dtype of column 1 which being used to sort, i made dtypes same in both, still output is not correct

Comment: @utk - what is `print (fields_df.info())` and  `print (fields_df1.info())` ? Can you add output to question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77696135/edit) ?

Comment: @utk - also if change types `print (out)` return something?